# Как удвоить символы с помощью списка массивов

Tags: java

Есть список массивов и необходимо добавить 5 строк, а потом удвоить значение, чтобы получилось следующее:

АА ББ ВВ ГГ ДД

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

for (int a = 0; a < 5; a++) {
    list.add(br.readLine());
}

for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++) {
    list.add(list.get(a));
}
```

Пытался сделать следующим образом, но вышло совсем не то, что ожидалось. Что именно, необходимо в этом случае сделать?

P.S. Если есть ответ, то прошу полностью не писать код

Comment: совершенно непонятно причем тут "аа бб вв гг дд" и список массивов и абстрактные 5 строк....и какое именно значение вы пытаетесь удвоить

Comment: Что именно непонятно? Необходимо добавить к абстрактному "а" еще одно "а", чтобы вышло "АА". Именно с помощью списка

Comment: стоп стоп стоп......... есть список массивов? где? нету его в коде........ необходимо добавить пять строк и `Необходимо добавить к абстрактному "а" еще одно "а"` ...... `а` - это символ...char....а не строка..... значит добавить нужно не 5 строк, а 5 чаров....

Comment: `P.S. Если есть ответ, то прошу полностью не писать код` первый раз такое вижу на SO 0_0. Это не курсы и не школа. Есть вопрос - есть ответ.

Comment: @DenisMatafonov а что слабо написать алгоритм или подсказки без кода?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский автор пишет код, указал даже язык - это не logic. Так что правильный ответ - это кусок кода, который решает поставленную задачу.

Comment: @DenisMatafonov правильный ответ это то, что поможет автору. А это может быть что угодно, хоть телефон службы поддержки языка программирования....Метка с языком указана для того, чтоб не сократить возможный богатый ответ и инструментарий и ответы были более специализированны... Например порекомендовать обратить вниманию на такую-то функцию, потому что... Присутствие метки языка не является показателем "код в ответе обязателен". Описать алгоритм также никто не запрещает, если он поможет автору

Comment: @АлексейШиманский именно поэтому все русскоязычные форумы и доски по программированию - помойки, а за ответами ходят на stackoverflow английский, где не позволят ответить телефоном службы поддержки.

Comment: @DenisMatafonov правильно, там сразу заминусуют и закроют вопрос и пошлют подальше

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно получить строку из `list` методом `get(...)`, далее *удвоить* ее и поместить на то же место в `list`, откуда она была получена.

```
for (int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
    String s = list.get(i);
    list.set(i, s + s);
}
```

Несколько замечаний:

1. > Есть список массивов

   Нет, нет у Вас никакого списка массивов, у Вас есть коллекция `ArrayList`, элементами которой являются объекты класса `String`.
2. Индексы в циклах общепринято именовать `i`, `j` и `k`.
3. После использования поток необходимо закрывать: `br.close();` (если не используется конструкция `try-with-resources`).

**UPD:**

В комментариях к этому ответу интересуются по поводу второго замечания, поэтому процитирую [Java code conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-150003.pdf):

> Common names for temporary variables are i, j, k,
>   m, and n for integers; c, d, and e for characters.

(*но вопрос вообще весьма странный*)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ и за критику, учту замечания

Comment: `Индексы в циклах принято именовать i, j и k` - кем принято?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Обществом, если хотите.

Comment: @post_zeew каким обществом? И причем тут какое-то общество?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Я совсем не понимаю, к чему этот вопрос, ибо я уверен, что с этим утверждением Вы согласны. Хорошо, пусть будет не обществом, а Java code conventions.

Comment: Если в решении будет прописано `list.set(i, s + s);` то результатом данного действия будет две одинаковые строки, написанные слитно, без пробелов, переносов на новую строку и т.д.
Например, если в данной строке `String s = "Leo";`, то вывод на экране будет: `LeoLeo` Это не нужно по условию, но вот что прикольно: прям в строке `(list.set(i, s + s);)` можно прописать перенос на новую строку, пробелы да и вообще дополнительные символы!!!